# php checking cookie to set another cookie

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

i'm setting a cookie using this code:

```
setcookie("Blah","user",time()+86400);
```

i'm then checking that cookie on another page and setting another cookie, then redirecting to another page

```
    if (isset($_COOKIE["Blah"]))
    {
        setcookie("Demo","user",time()+86400);
    }
$url="cd/bar/home.php"
header ("Location: $URL");
```

however, when it gets to the redirected page it's acting as if the second cookie isn't set (if it matters the second page is in a different subdirectory, so i'm going from .com/fu/home.php to .com/bar/home.php)

on the redirected page i've got this checking the second cookie

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["Demo"]))
{
?>
html
<?php
}
?>
```

i have no idea why it's not recognizing that the cookie is set.  i know for a fact that the check for the first cookie is working as expected.

Comment: have you started session before using cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page for [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> The default value [of the `$path` argument] is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

So the cookie is only being set with the `/fu/` path.  If you want to set it to the global path, say so explicitly:

```
setcookie("Demo","user",time()+86400, '/');
```

Comment: i figured there was comething like that, i just couldn't find it.  thank you.  when i get time to try it again and make sure it works i'll accept this as the answer.